# JavaScript: How to run a function several time with different arguments?

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, arguments, factory-pattern

I'm using ExtJS framework and a run one method multiple times with different parameters.

I'm looking a way to make it more consist, easy and maintainable and I guess just vanilla Javascript solutions could handle this?

I've tried to collect each param into array and using `Array.map()` as well `forEach()` methods but I couldn't handle it.

Thanks for advance.

```
//ExtJS class:
Ext.define('MyApp.FooClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    items: [
        MyApp.createFooCard('Func1Param1', 'Func1Param2', 'Func1Param3'),
        MyApp.createFooCard('Func2Param1', 'Func2Param2', 'Func2Param3'),
        MyApp.createFooCard('Func3Param1', 'Func3Param2', 'Func3Param3'),
    ]
});
```

As you'll notice I totaly use same method but different arguments for each of them.

```
//And here is related factory-function:
createFooCard: (bindValue, userCls, glyph, label) => {
        return {
            itemId: bindValue,
            userCls: userCls,
            glyph: MyApp.getGlyph(glyph),
            items: {
                xtype: 'infocardfld',
                fieldLabel: label,
                bind: '{' + bindValue + ' || "0"}'
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to collect nested arrays and relaying those arrays with [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to run on factory-function. It should be:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.FooClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    items: [
              ['Func1Param1', 'Func1Param2', 'Func1Param3'],
              ['Func2Param1', 'Func2Param2', 'Func2Param3'],
              ['Func3Param1', 'Func3Param2', 'Func3Param3']
           ].map(args => MyApp.createFooCard(...args));
    });
```

Comment: I've tried `Array.map()` but got error. I just noticed you've used `rest parameters` within `map`.. I've implement `...args` as parameter for my own factory function and now it's working. Thanks.

Comment: but I guess it'll be better to underline `rest parameters` on your response for other people good. So They could understand why not only `args` alias doesn't work but `...args` works.

Comment: @NuriEngin You're welcome. Here, the `...` is not `rest` but `spread`

Comment: Ohh! I just edited your answer. Could you please re-edit it.

Comment: Dear @Faly is this arrangement could be possible for a object: 
`formulas: {totalCountIC: MyApp.cardReq('TOTALCOUNT'),totalTaskIC: MyApp.cardReq('TOTALTASK')}`

Answer (score 0):

If this `Items` array is in the global scope you could easily add elements to it inside the `createFooCard` function. As a example:

// Your element collection array

```
var items = []
```

//Your function

```
function createFooCard(bindValue, userCls, glyph, label) {
    var temp = {
        itemId: bindValue,
        userCls: userCls,
        glyph: MyApp.getGlyph(glyph),
        items: {
            xtype: 'infocardfld',
            fieldLabel: label,
            bind: '{' + bindValue + ' || "0"}'
        }
    };

    items.push(temp);
}
```

You could easily pass the array as a param as well. if you wants to make it more generalized.